# I have hosted a MVC applicaton on 64 bit with database of remedy 7 on 32 bit driver. While retrieving data from DB, app pool is crashing.

Tags: asp.net-mvc, 64-bit, remedy

Tried increasing the thread counts, checked with logging but still not giving any logs as app pool is crashing

Comment: You need to give more info on the setup.

Comment: We are trying to host a ASP.NET MVC project on a windows server 2008 with IIS 7.0. The project hosting is successful in the DefaultAppPool and the website is accessible. However when it comes to the point where we need to fetch data from a Remedy database the worker process crashes with the below error in the event viewer:
 
Rest in below comment

Comment: Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7a5f8
Faulting module name: mswsock.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7b8e8
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x0000179e
Faulting process id: 0x1b74
Faulting application start time: 0x01cfcdc0d847ee04
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\mswsock.dll
Report Id: 172c4d88-39b4-11e4-ab17-d89d6729112b

Comment: The windows is 64-bit windows and due to requirements we had to build and deploy it as a 32-bit application. Let us know for any further info required.